# Memory allocation in c & libjpeg

Tags: segmentation-fault, jpeg, libjpeg

I've been working on an image processing project where I have to write everything in C and use libjpeg library because there is no alternative on the machine that I am using and I am specifically forbidden to install new libs.

Now I'm only having problem with the reading JPEG loop in the read_JPEG_file, that is where Segmentation fault (core dumped) error occurs. To be exact, the error is on jpeg_scan_lines  jpeg_read_scanlines(&cinfo, &ptr, 1); What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <time.h>
//#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
//include <stdbool.h>
//#include <cstring>
#include <string.h>   
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include "doc/turbojpeg.h"
//#include <jmorecfg.h>
#include <jerror.h>
#include <jconfig.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <jpeglib.h>
#define NUM_IMAGES 100

typedef struct
{
    unsigned char *pixels;  /* Points to large array of R,G,B-order data */
    unsigned long height;        /* Number of rows in image */
    unsigned long width;         /* Number of columns in image */
}ImageData;



struct my_error_mgr 
{
  struct jpeg_error_mgr pub;    /* "public" fields */

  jmp_buf setjmp_buffer;        /* for return to caller */
};

typedef struct my_error_mgr * my_error_ptr;


METHODDEF(void) my_error_exit (j_common_ptr cinfo)
{
    my_error_ptr myerr = (my_error_ptr) cinfo->err;
    (*cinfo->err->output_message) (cinfo);
    longjmp(myerr->setjmp_buffer, 1);
}

int READ_JPEG_FILE (char * filename, ImageData * image)
{
    int bytes_per_pixel = 3;
    struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;
    struct my_error_mgr jerr;

    unsigned char *ptr = NULL;
        unsigned int i, ipos;

    FILE * infile=NULL; 
    printf("%s\n","initializations done for reading JPEG");              
    //if file can't be opened
    if ((infile = fopen(filename, "rb")) == NULL) 
    {
            fprintf(stderr, "can't open %s\n", filename);
            return 0;
    }
    //override standard error
    cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerr.pub);
    jerr.pub.error_exit = my_error_exit;
    //define what must be done when error occurs
    if (setjmp(jerr.setjmp_buffer))
    {
            jpeg_destroy_decompress(&cinfo);
            fclose(infile);
        return 0;
    }   
    printf("%s\n","Overriden error messages, yey mom!");
    jpeg_create_decompress(&cinfo);
    jpeg_stdio_src(&cinfo, infile);
    jpeg_read_header(&cinfo, TRUE);
    jpeg_start_decompress(&cinfo);
    long *w =malloc(sizeof(unsigned long));
    long *h=malloc(sizeof(unsigned long));
    w = &cinfo.output_width;
    h = &cinfo.output_height;
    printf("%s%d%s%d%s","The dimensions are: ", &w, " by width and ", &h, " by height.\n");


    printf("%s", "Standard functions are called, reading the JPEG now.\n");
        while (cinfo.output_scanline < cinfo.output_height) 
        {
            jpeg_read_scanlines(&cinfo, &ptr, 1);
            ptr += 3 * cinfo.output_width;
        }
    printf("%s\n", "reading is finished");
    image->pixels=ptr;
    image->width = *w;
    image->height = *h;
        jpeg_finish_decompress(&cinfo);
        jpeg_destroy_decompress(&cinfo);
    free(w); free(h); free(ptr);
        return(1);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%s","Start the damn program already.\n");
    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dent;
    printf("%s","directory objects are created successfully.\n");
    d = opendir("./holidays");
    printf("%s","Obtained the image directory.\n");
    ImageData *database;
    database = malloc(NUM_IMAGES * (sizeof(ImageData)));
    printf("%s", "Allocated memory for database.\n");
    if (d)
    {
        int i=0;
        printf("%d%s", i,".\n");
        dent = readdir(d);
            while (dent != NULL)
            {
            char * temp = dent->d_name;
            char * name = strtok(temp, ".");
            char * foldur = "./holidays/";
            char * path = strcat(name, ".jpg");
            printf("%s\n",path);
            char * currentPath = (char*)malloc(strlen(foldur)+strlen(path));
            strcpy(currentPath, foldur);            
            printf("%s\n",currentPath);
            currentPath = strcat(currentPath,name);
            printf("%s\n",currentPath);
            if(currentPath!=NULL)
            {
                printf("%s\n", "inside loop mom");
                ImageData imRead;
                printf("%s%d%s","Getting ready for image number ", i, "...\n");  
                if(READ_JPEG_FILE(currentPath, &imRead))
                {
                    database[i] = imRead;
                    i++;
                }
                //free(imRead);
            }
            free(temp); free(name); free(foldur); free(path);       free(currentPath);
            }
            closedir(d);
        printf("%d%s", i, " of the 100 images are processed.\n");
    }
    free(database);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which line does the error happen on?

Comment: Now I have a problem with the reading loop

Comment: Specifically on the read_scan_lines function, I call it with the header, unsigned char * ptr. Should I use JSAMPARRAY instead?

Answer (score 0):

I'd wager this is causing a problem:

> long *w,*h;
>       * w = cinfo.output_width;
>       * h = cinfo.output_height;

Comment: Yes, I needed to malloc and get the value of the cinfo variables. But now, I have a problem with the reading loop
     while (cinfo.output_scanline < cinfo.output_height) 
     {
            jpeg_read_scanlines(&cinfo, &ptr, 1);
            ptr += 3 * cinfo.output_width;
     }